# How to make bit ignore a dependency file?

Tags: node.js, npm, bit, code-sharing, bit-src

We have a current ReactJS project and we build a custom grid, input, error handler, etc for it.
now we start a new project and we want to share our components code between projects. we do some research and find bit platform [bitsrc.io](http://bitsrc.io)
so pleasant and good and we actually share some code between our projects with it.
the only problem is bit has a dependency checker for the import statement.
we add most of the dependency to bit lifeCycle but some of them is a config file and we want them to be different in our projects.
can anyone know the way we could ignore config import dependency to the bit?

```
//make bit ignore this file in dependency checking 
import GeneralConfig from 'Modules/GeneralConfig/GeneralConfig'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you ignore a dependency in [bit](https://github.com/teambit/bit), the component will not be truly reusable. This is becasue other projects may lack a dependency for the component to function.

To ignore a missing dependency, use the `--ignore-missing-dependencies` for the `bit tag` command.

What I suggest is for you to inject the configuration to the component, rather than having the component depending on the configuration.

Comment: For other people like me that maybe face this issue, put --ignore-missing-dependencies exactly after tag, means: "bit tag --ignore-missing-dependencies --all 1.0.0", for example, this command will not work as you expected: "bit tag --all --ignore-missing-dependencies 1.0.0"